# android - ffmpeg overlay videos not working properly

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg

What I'm trying to do: I have 2 videos (the first one is recorded in the app itself, the second was pre-recorded and it's shorter than the first). I'm trying to overlay it with the following FFMpeg command:

```
finalCommand = new String[]{"-y",
                "-i", vid1,
                "-i", vid2,
                "-i", aud1,
                "-i", aud2,
                "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",
                        "[0:a] volume=0.2 [a8];"
                        +"[3:a] atrim=end="+String.valueOf(newTimePause)+" [a12];"
                        +"[3:a] atrim=start="+String.valueOf(newTimePause)+" [a14];"
                        +"[a14] adelay="+String.valueOf(newDelayInt)+"|"
                        +String.valueOf(newDelayInt)+" [a16];"
                        + "[a8][a12][a16][2:a:0] amix=inputs=4 [a];"
                        + "movie=" + watermark + " [watermark];"
                        + "[0:v][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [outv0];"
                        + "[1] fifo, scale=iw/2.5:ih/2.5 [vid2];"
                        + "[vid2]fifo, trim=end=80.5 [vid5];"
                        + "[vid2] fifo, trim=start=80.5 [vid6];"
                        + "[outv0][vid5] overlay=10:10:enable=\'between(t,0,84)\' [outv6];"
                        + "[outv6][vid6] overlay=10:10:enable=\'between(t,84,101)\' [outv]",
                "-map", "[outv]",
                "-map", "[a]",
                "-r", "30",
                "-b",
                "4000k",
                "-vcodec", "mpeg4",
                "-ab", "44100", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "44100",
                IOUtils.getFINALdir(this)+"/finalvid.mp4"
        };
```

So: vid1 is an mp4 video recorded in the app, watermark is a png image that should be overlayed during all vid1, and vid2 is the one pre-recorded. And the difference in length between vid1 and vid2 depends on the user. So I need to split vid2 at 80.5 seconds into 2 pieces, then overlay the first piece of vid2 from the beginning of vid1 to the time user clicked the button (here it's hardcoded as *84* for convenience, and I know that from 80.5 to 84 the last frame will remain overlaid - it's ok), then overlay the second piece from this "84" till the end. (it's almost the same for aud2 - the corresponding audio for vid2 - but aud2 works fine)

But with this piece of code it looks like it takes a lot of memory and lots of frames of overlaid vid2 just get lost - it just freezes. And the line `+ "[outv6][vid6] overlay=10:10:enable=\'between(t,84,101)\' [outv]",` ruins everything so that from 84 till the end **nothing is finally overlaid** including the watermark (why so?)

And the other problem is this is too slow. Idk how to export a video of 720p or 1080p and that it be not too slow, not be of a big file size and not stop with OOM (now it's about 480p and takes about 50Mb - I want a larger resolution with a smaller size).

I think the whole command can be rewritten better, but how? What am I doing wrong and how to fix it all? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for the video part:

```
                    + "movie=" + watermark + " [watermark];"
                    + "[1]scale=iw/2.5:ih/2.5,split[vid2a][vid2b];"
                    + "[vid2a]trim=end=80.5,fifo[vid2a-ol];"
                    + "[vid2b]trim=start=80.5,setpts=PTS+3.5/TB,fifo[vid2b-ol];"
                    + "[0][vid2a-ol]overlay=10:10:enable=\'between(t,0,84)\',fifo[outv1];"
                    + "[outv1][vid2b-ol]overlay=10:10:enable=\'between(t,84,101)\',fifo[outv12];",
                    + "[outv12][watermark]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10 [outv0]"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But the first overlaid piece still freezes at about very first frame :(

Comment: Try with fifo added

Comment: to the last line? or to the "split" part too?

Comment: seems to be working fine, thank you so much!

And one more question, can I accelerate the process without losing quality? Or decrease final video size?

Comment: If you need to stick with codec `mpeg4`, decrease the `-b` value. If not, switch to `-vcodec libx264` and drop the `-b`